# How to get Grouped Product Name in Checkout Magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am trying to make a shopping cart using `magneto`.

The single products only have titles like S, M, L, XL and no product name. The product name is too long to display it everywhere. It should only be displayed in cart and checkout.

I am not able to get any parent IDs of the product. I used following code for this

```
$grouped_product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getSku());

print_r($grouped_product_ids);

if (!empty($grouped_product_ids)){
    echo $grouped_product_ids()->getName(); //product name;
};
```

How can I get the ID of the Grouped Product? Or how can I get the name of the Grouped Product?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
$grouped_product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getSku());

print_r($grouped_product_ids);

if (!empty($grouped_product_ids)){
foreach($grouped_product_ids as $grouped_product_id)
{
$grpProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($grouped_product_id);
echo $grpProduct->getName();
}
}
```

Comment: The problem ist, that the aray is empty by using:
    $grouped_product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getSku());

I'm using this code in \app\design\frontend\default\hellonikola\template\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml

I can't get any parent category ID. Is there an other way?

Comment: Try this one in item.phtml

$_product = $this->getProduct();
    $grouped_product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getSku());